# Why does uniq seem to keep some consecutive identical lines?

Tags: text-processing, uniq

Without uniq:

```
amin@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cut -f 1 info.log | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | sort
Abol
Abol 
Ahmad
Akbar
Arash
Hadi 
Hamed
Mahmood
Maryam
Maryam
Mohsen
NIma
Rasool
Sadegh
Sepide
Sepide
```

With uniq:

```
amin@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cut -f 1 info.log | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | sort | uniq
Abol
Abol 
Ahmad
Akbar
Arash
Hadi 
Hamed
Mahmood
Maryam
Mohsen
NIma
Rasool
Sadegh
Sepide
Sepide
```

As you see result are same in both, why?

Comment: Hint: you have trailing spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR: The lines have different whitespace (possibly spaces) at the end.

This happens when you have lines that look the same but are are actually different due to characters that don't display in your terminal, usually at the end. Often these are are trailing spaces (as [fkraiem suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168621/uniq-command-not-working-well#comment1949583_1168621)) or inconsistent [line terminators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation).

You might expect that starting the pipeline, as you do, with `cut`, would prevent this. It doesn't, though. `cut` uses a tab as its default delimiter. (Readers who wish to verify this behavior--and its relevance to having unexpected duplicate lines after `uniq`--can try `cut -f 1 <<<$'foo\nfoo  ' | uniq`, which prints two lines.)

The solution in your case is probably to use something other than `cut -f 1` to select the fields. In particular, if the fields are separated by spaces instead of tabs--whether by a single space or multiple spaces, and even if the number of spaces is different in different records--then you can use `cut -d' ' -f 1` instead, specifying space as the delimiter character. Or you might not want to use `cut` at all, but instead use `awk '{ print $1 }'`, which prints the first field, taking any sequence of consecutive spaces and tabs as the delimiter.

You could alternatively strip the trailing whitespace, though this makes your command even more complicated. One way to do that would be by piping your text through `sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+$//'` before it goes to `uniq`.

As a side note, if whatever command you ultimately use still ends up piping the output of `sort` directly to `uniq`, you might consider just using `sort -u` for that instead.

Comment: Thanks, this option worked for me: sed -E 's/[[:space:]]+$//'